# Documentation or examples of WinRTXamlToolkit.UWP

Tags: uwp, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I've just installed the package but I have no idea of how to use it. I'm retrieving errors so I'm wondering if I am doing something wrong :S

Is there any documentation or examples or something? I've been searching around the GitHub but I've just found the source code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you need help with the errors - you'd need to say what errors you get. If you're seeing them in the XAML design view - it's expected. The toolkit doesn't work very well in the designer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloning or downloading the source code should help since there's a project with samples in it.